# SQL Server 2000 (8.0) SP 4 crash after load Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server

Hello I configured one Oracle 10g Linked Server on my SQL Server 2000, so two days ago I can view the tables and views, today when I try to check it again I get an connection error, something with latency and time out operation "readsni" in the process of login the sa user.

Then I lost all connections and have to restart the SQL Server.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a screen capture of the error?

Comment: no screenshoots just freeze and then SQL Service is down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the linked server settings you used (connection timeout, query timeout, etc)?

Comment: both, I have to removed a login has been locked on the linked server